# Не могу правильно конвертировать значение строки

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня строка
`"0.7,0.5,0.5,0.4,-0.5,-0.7,0.7,-0.8,-0.6,-0.8,0.4,-0.7,0.4,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3"`
как мне её конвертировать в numbers или float?
Я уже всё перерыл:(

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Решил вопрос, спасибо Всем кто дал подсказки, в особенности teran.
Я сделал это вот так.
playerData[12] = result[0].faceFeatures//тут была строка с бд

ответ вот такой
playerData[12] = result[0].faceFeatures.split( ',' ).map( parseFloat );
обращаюсь по индексу(так как у меня playerData[12] это переменная в массиве и добавляю новый индекс[0], т.е результат будет таким playerData[12][0]  где [0] - это 0.7)

Answer (score 1):

разделить по запятой и привести к числу?

```js
const str = "0.7,0.5,0.5,0.4,-0.5,-0.7,0.7,-0.8,-0.6,-0.8,0.4,-0.7,0.4,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3";

let res = str.split(",").map(v => +v);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: А он его в объект разве не превращает?

Comment: @Edwards1337 "он его" - кто кого?